# How to create a trait with a method that requires the implementors to implement serde::Deserialize

Tags: serialization, rust, lifetime, serde

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e2e6db8a9312f415adf3b942796f45f)

I have a few structs that are deserialized from TOML files using `from_path()` methods. To prevent copied code I tried to create a trait with generic methods to do this that I could just implement like this

```
impl FromTomlFile for MyStruct {}
```

Unfortunately because of the lifetime parameter on `serde::Deserialize` this is not as simple as I thought it would be.

```
use serde;
use serde_derive::Deserialize; // 1.0.88
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;
use toml; // 0.4.10

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct A {}

trait FromTomlFile<'de>
where
    Self: Sized + serde::Deserialize<'de>,
{
    fn from_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<Self, toml::de::Error> {
        toml::from_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&fs::read(&path).unwrap()))
    }
}

impl FromTomlFile for A {} // <-- doesn't work
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Deserialize` with [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) - this allows you to get rid of the explicit lifetime `'de`:

```rust
trait FromTomlFile
where
    Self: Sized + serde::de::DeserializeOwned,
// etc
```